# Render Preview / Actual Render Reduces Resolution of Source Video to 1080p from 1440p (Video Editing)

Tags: video

brand new to blender here. I am experiencing the below issue. Assistance appreciated!

1. The source video resolution is 1440p (as seen in bottom right of image)
2. The output format of the project is 1440p (as seen in top right of image)
3. The preview window (on the left side of the image) shows the source video as 1080p with checkerboarding to fill in space to 1440p. (If I decreased the output resolution to 1080p there would be no more checkerboard, hence my conclusion).
4. Why is blender messing up the resolution of the source video? The video should take up the full space (1440p) as it itself is 1440p, not 1080p.

I've confirmed its not just the preview. After rendering the video, the rendered video's content is smaller than the source video's content when played in vlc.

[image]

Comment: can u share your blend file?

Comment: Take a look at the Video "Sequencer >> Preview" panel to the left of your scene properties.   Does "Image >> Apply >> Scale To Fit" make a difference?   I often overlook doing this and my output can be a subset of the video output screen.   You don't have to wait to output the whole video to check, BTW... just ctrl-F12 for some 15 secs and then run the resulting video.

Comment: Looks like that worked! On the timeline tabs: "Image -> Apply -> Scale To Fit".